# Which statement to use based on its row and transaction in stay that way

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting stuck on this, hard to explain to write down here as well the subject heading hopefully by the data example and output result below that enough to give you an idea.

I am run out which Oracle SQL statement best to use. The over (partition) seem didn't work out for the below scenario.

Before & After:

[image]

**DATA**

| customer_id | row_id | date | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LB01 | 22 | 14/03/2022 | CAR 1 |
| LB01 | 21 | 11/03/2022 | CAR 1 |
| LB01 | 20 | 9/11/2001 | CAR 1 |
| LB01 | 19 | 16/10/2001 | CAR 1 |
| LB01 | 18 | 10/08/2001 | CAR 2 |
| LB01 | 17 | 29/05/2001 | CAR 2 |
| LB01 | 16 | 24/04/2001 | CAR 2 |
| LB01 | 15 | 13/03/2001 | CAR 3 |
| LB01 | 14 | 21/12/2000 | CAR 3 |
| LB01 | 13 | 13/11/2000 | CAR 3 |
| LB01 | 12 | 20/10/2000 | CAR 3 |
| LB01 | 11 | 14/03/2000 | CAR 1 |
| LB01 | 10 | 18/01/2000 | CAR 1 |
| LB01 | 9 | 24/12/1999 | CAR 2 |
| LB01 | 8 | 14/09/1999 | CAR 2 |
| LB01 | 7 | 30/03/1999 | CAR 2 |
| LB01 | 6 | 24/02/1999 | CAR 2 |
| LB01 | 5 | 19/02/1999 | CAR 4 |
| LB01 | 4 | 15/12/1998 | CAR 4 |
| LB01 | 3 | 15/12/1998 | CAR 4 |
| LB01 | 2 | 24/09/1998 | CAR 4 |
| LB01 | 1 | 06/08/1998 | CAR 4 |

The output that I want result like this:

| customer_id | type | min_date | max_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LB01 | Car 1 | 16/10/2001 | 14/03/2002 |
| LB01 | Car 2 | 24/04/2001 | 10/08/2001 |
| LB01 | Car 3 | 20/10/2000 | 13/03/2001 |
| LB01 | Car 1 | 18/01/2000 | 14/03/2000 |
| LB01 | Car 2 | 24/02/1999 | 24/12/1999 |
| LB01 | Car 4 | 6/08/1998 | 19/02/1999 |

I hope those makes sense for you and hopefully you can assist me on this.

Comment: Is this first table with row_id the table with the input data or is that already the result of a query? If it's not the original table, could you please add it?

Comment: Can’t you just select the min and max dates grouped by customer_id and type?

Comment: @JonasMetzler There are more columns alas can't share actual data due to sensitive data only I can give those an example where each row that sort of paragraph that I want to output the result on each type on each process from A to B to C to B to C to A etc

Comment: @NickW I tried that it picked up on the oldest date on the whole customer ID based on type not on the rows/paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create your own grouping calculation out of already existing ROW_ID and use MIN_DATE for ordering:

```sql
SELECT  CUST_ID, A_TYPE, Min(A_DATE) "MIN_DATE", Max(A_DATE) "MAX_DATE" 
FROM    (SELECT     t.*,
                    Max(ROW_ID) OVER(Partition By CUST_ID || A_TYPE ORDER BY ROW_ID DESC Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) -
                    (ROW_ID + Sum(1) OVER(PARTITION BY CUST_ID || A_TYPE ORDER BY ROW_ID DESC) - 1) "GRP"
        FROM        tbl t
        ORDER BY    ROW_ID DESC     )
GROUP BY    CUST_ID, A_TYPE, GRP
ORDER BY    CUST_ID, MIN(A_DATE) DESC
```

With your sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl (CUST_ID,   ROW_ID, A_DATE, A_TYPE) AS
        (   Select 'LB01',  22, To_Date('14/03/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 1' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LB01',  21, To_Date('11/03/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 1' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LB01',  20, To_Date('09/11/2001', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 1' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LB01',  19, To_Date('16/10/2001', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 1' From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 'LB01',  18, To_Date('10/08/2001', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 2' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LB01',  17, To_Date('29/05/2001', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 2' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LB01',  16, To_Date('24/04/2001', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 2' From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 'LB01',  15, To_Date('13/03/2001', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 3' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LB01',  14, To_Date('21/12/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 3' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LB01',  13, To_Date('13/11/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 3' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LB01',  12, To_Date('20/10/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 3' From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 'LB01',  11, To_Date('14/03/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 1' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LB01',  10, To_Date('18/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 1' From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 'LB01',  9,  To_Date('24/12/1999', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 2' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LB01',  8,  To_Date('14/09/1999', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 2' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LB01',  7,  To_Date('30/03/1999', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 2' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LB01',  6,  To_Date('24/02/1999', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 2' From Dual Union All
            --
            Select 'LB01',  5,  To_Date('19/02/1999', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 4' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LB01',  4,  To_Date('15/12/1998', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 4' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LB01',  3,  To_Date('15/12/1998', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 4' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LB01',  2,  To_Date('24/09/1998', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 4' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LB01',  1,  To_Date('06/08/1998', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),    'CAR 4' From Dual
        )
```

R e s u l t :

| CUST_ID | A_TYPE | MIN_DATE | MAX_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LB01 | CAR 1 | 16-OCT-01 | 14-MAR-22 |
| LB01 | CAR 2 | 24-APR-01 | 10-AUG-01 |
| LB01 | CAR 3 | 20-OCT-00 | 13-MAR-01 |
| LB01 | CAR 1 | 18-JAN-00 | 14-MAR-00 |
| LB01 | CAR 2 | 24-FEB-99 | 24-DEC-99 |
| LB01 | CAR 4 | 06-AUG-98 | 19-FEB-99 |

Comment: @d r    thank you so much now it works on my data as long as I create a new column for new row number =>row_number() over(partition by cust_id order by seq_id  ) row_id  due to my date has row number sequence number is not in orderly, thank you again for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply Tabibitosan algorithm first:

```
select customer_id, type, rn, min(dat) as min_date, max(dat) as max_dat
from (
    select d.*, row_id+1-row_number() over(partition by customer_id, type order by row_id) as rn 
    from data d
)
group by customer_id, type, rn
order by customer_id, type
;

CUST TYPE          RN MIN_DATE MAX_DAT 
---- ----- ---------- -------- --------
LB01 CAR 1         10 18/01/00 14/03/00
LB01 CAR 1         17 16/10/01 14/03/22
LB01 CAR 2          6 24/02/99 24/12/99
LB01 CAR 2         12 24/04/01 10/08/01
LB01 CAR 3         12 20/10/00 13/03/01
LB01 CAR 4          1 06/08/98 19/02/99
```

Comment: thank you for the Tabibitosan algorithm that I never knew.

I tried your method on my end, and somehow min and max dates are the same as the origin date

Comment: Share what you have done then

Comment: that's the same as you show me only a different column name in the ORACLE SQL script.

also, I tried not to include "rn", it shows everything from oldest and latest date in min and max date which are grouped types in summary and the result is not what I want.

I googled more about Tabibitosan still trying to understand how it works as well the way you execute seems to work but my data result didn't work at all, I need more tweaking my skills on further SQL script, not just hardcore

Comment: not including "rn" - that I should have named "grp" for group - will of course not work. The idea  of Tabibitosan is to calculate a group id for consecutive data: here the row_id, by removing the row_number() of each row from the row_id, so rows separated by 1 on the row_id and consecutive in the row_number() ordering will have the same "group" (delta = +1 -1 = 0), since any gap in row_id means a delta>=2 while the delta of row_number() remains 1 (delta = +2 - 1  = 1) , so the "group" changes...
At the end you can apply any analytic function on the resulting numbering of the "group".

Comment: hmmmm... even I tried to create its new column for row number since the row_id is not in order number in sub query use row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by id_seq) as row_2  still didn't work too, anyway I wish you a Merry Christmas and thank you for helping me this, I need to switch off my brain to stop thinking about this work stuff :)

Comment: thank you so much now it works on my data as long as I create new column for row number =>row_number() over(partition by cust_id order by seq_id  ) row_id  due to my date has row number sequence number are not in orderly, thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0):

refer to the above post made by @p3consulting regarding the Tabibitosan algorithm

here is the below script that you can copy and paste into your Oracle SQL to learn

for my question here still does not work for my data and still searching the right script

```
with
sample_data (customer_id, row_id, mock_date, product_type) as (
select 'LB01', '22', to_date ('03/14/22', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 1' from dual union all    
select 'LB01', '21', to_date ('03/11/22', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 1' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '20', to_date ('11/09/01', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 1' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '19', to_date ('10/16/01', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 1' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '18', to_date ('08/10/01', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 2' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '17', to_date ('05/29/01', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 2' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '16', to_date ('04/24/01', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 2' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '15', to_date ('03/13/01', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 3' from dual union all    
select 'LB01', '14', to_date ('12/21/00', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 3' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '13', to_date ('11/13/00', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 3' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '12', to_date ('10/20/00', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 3' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '11', to_date ('03/14/00', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 1' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '10', to_date ('01/18/00', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 1' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '09', to_date ('12/24/99', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 2' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '08', to_date ('09/14/99', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 2' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '07', to_date ('03/30/99', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 2' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '06', to_date ('02/24/99', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 2' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '05', to_date ('02/19/99', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 4' from dual union all    
select 'LB01', '04', to_date ('12/15/98', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 4' from dual union all    
select 'LB01', '03', to_date ('12/15/98', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 4' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '02', to_date ('09/24/98', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 4' from dual union all
select 'LB01', '01', to_date ('06/08/98', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'CAR 4' from dual 
)
 
select
customer_id ,
product_type ,
grp ,
min(mock_date) as min_date , 
max(mock_date) as max_date 
from (
select d.* ,
row_id + 1 - row_number () over (partition by customer_id, product_type order by row_id) as grp
from sample_data d )
 
group by
customer_id ,
product_type ,
grp 
 
order by
grp desc
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**PLEASE NOTE:** For some reason this website can't tick both answers that the solution provided by @p3consulting and @d r are working on my data by creating a new column for a new row id in that way row numbers are in orderly

subquery before that;

> row_number() over(partition by cust_id order by seq_id  ) row_id

depend on how your data has numbers are not in orderly number